# How to serialize IDictionary

Tags: c#

Does anyone know of a creative way to serialize objects that implement IDictionary? ...without implementing a new class?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the class implementing `IDictionary` is serializable (like [`Dictionary<K,V>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)) and `K` and `V` are serializable then the standard .NET serialization mechanisms should work.

If the class implementing `IDictionary` is serializable but `K` and `V` are then you could use two arrays to serialize the keys and associated values separately:

```
// before serialization
IDictionary<string,int> dict;
string[] keys = dict.Keys.ToArray();
int[] values = dict.Keys.Select(key => dict[key]).ToArray();

// after deserialization
IDictionary<string,int> dict = new Dictionary<string,int>();
for (int i = 0; i < keys.Length; i++)
    dict.Add(keys[i], values[i]);
```

Comment: Due to some crazy accessors that I have in the class, I was unable to implement this particular solution, but it was the type of creative solution I was looking for... so I'll mark this as the answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I take it you mean you have to serialize a dictionary that's part of class you have no control over?

In short, you have to serialize the keys and values separately. To deserialize, step through each item in the key/value arrays and add them back to your dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer`, with `ReadObject` and `WriteObject` the same way as you would do `Deserialize` and `Serialize`.
It works like a charm.

Comment: Will it serialize / deserialize inline? Meaning, the main serialization is xml, but it can inject just for the IDictionary property that is causing the problem?