# Calling a parameterless method from a web service error

Tags: c#, web-services

I'm trying to call a web service method which returns an ID of a company

```
GetCompanyCommand companyRef = new GetCompany();
```

but I have a method in the web service that already exists and the constructor has a parameter

```
public GetCompanyCommand(Guid actCompanyId)
    {
        this.actCompanyId = actCompanyId;

    }
```

The problem is when i go to update the Web Service reference i am presented with an error that says the method cannot be serialised because it does not contain a parameterless constructor.

Now is there a way for me to fix this without changing the existing constructor? Because many other methods already call it.

Comment: Just add a parameterless constructor to your service class ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your web service class has a constructor with parameter than it should have parameterless constructor. like

```
public GetCompany()
{

}
```

This is a limitation of `XmlSerializer`. Note that `BinaryFormatter` and `DataContractSerializer` do not require this - they can create an uninitialized object out of the ether and initialize it during deserialization.

During an object's `de-serialization`, the class responsible for de-serializing an object creates an `instance` of the serialized class and then proceeds to populate the serialized fields and properties only after acquiring an instance to populate.

Comment: when i use the empty parameterless constructor i then get an error:
_cannot serialise member System.Exception.Data of type System.Collection.Dictionary because it implements IDictionary_ ???

Comment: @dizzytri99er this exception does not relate to your first one, its another issue

Comment: @dizzytri99er chk this thread... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363894/how-to-serialize-idictionary