# Cast a less specified interface IInterface to a more specified IInterface<TKey,TValue>?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, interface, casting

I have two interfaces

```
public interface ISerializableDictionary { ... }
public interface ISerializableDictionary<TKey,TValue>
    : ISerializableDictionary { ... }
```

I need to cast from the former to the latter at run time using reflection.

It's clearly easy to interrogate the former with `GetType().GetGenericArguments`.

But how do I then do the cast?  I have this code below but it is failing to compile, for the obvious reason that I am trying to use a variable as a type.

```
Type[] genericTypes = dictionary.GetType().GenericTypeArguments;
Type keyType = genericTypes[0];
Type valueType = genericTypes[1];

// this compiles but doesn't do the cast
Type dictType = typeof(SerializableDictionary<,>).MakeGenericType(keyType, valueType);
var createdDictionary = Activator.CreateInstance(dictType);

// this is the line that won't compile - 'dictionary' is a SerializableDictionary, and I want to access it through its typed generic interface
ISerializableDictionary<keyType,valueType> serializableDictionary = dictionary as ISerializableDictionary<keyType, valueType>;
```

The more specified interface has a method which I need to call.  The less specified interface does not (and can't ever be, because the call needs a typed argument).

Is the solution something to do with `dictionary.GetType().GetInterfaces()`?

Any steer will be wildly appreciated.  Programming solo at the moment so I don't have a team to call on, hence the query here.

---

**UPDATE - in response to comments**

The problem I am trying to solve is how to serialize members of an object where the members are themselves enumerable.  I am trying to figure out how serialization libraries do it as a learning exercise and because I have a few ideas that I want to explore.  Serialization & Reflection are not my main areas of programming so I am stumbling to learn them.

So I have (as reduced code):

```
public class ExperimentalSerializer<T>
{

    public void Serialize(T objectToSerialize)
    {

        IEnumerable<object> collectionsToSerializeToCSV = objectToSerialize.GetEnumerableMembers();
        foreach (object collectionToSerialize in collectionsToSerializeToCSV)
        {

            string csvString      = "";
            if (collectionToSerialize.IsDictionary())
            {
                // serialize dictionary here to csvString
                // but cannot properly access contents through just IDictionary
                // need IDictionary<TKey,TValue>
                // ** ALSO SEE TEXT BELOW THIS CODE SNIPPET**
            }
            else if (collectionToSerialize.IsList())
            {
                // serialize list here to csvString
            }
            else if (collectionToSerialize.GetType().IsArray)
            {
                // serialize array here to csvString
            }

            // save csvString to somewhere useful here

        }

    }

}
```

And elsewhere I have an extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<object> GetEnumerableMembers(this object objectToInterrogate)
{
    Type                      objectType               = objectToInterrogate.GetType();

    // get the enumerable properties
    PropertyInfo[]            properties               = objectType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
    IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> enumerableProperties     = properties.Where(propertInfo => propertInfo.PropertyType.GetInterfaces().Any(x => x == typeof(IEnumerable)));
    IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> serializableProperties   = enumerableProperties.Where(p => p.IsSerializable());
    IEnumerable<object>       enumerablePropertyValues = serializableProperties.Select(p => p.GetValue(objectToInterrogate, null));

    // get the enumerable fields
    FieldInfo[]               fields                   = objectType.GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
    IEnumerable<FieldInfo>    enumerablefields         = fields.Where(propertInfo => propertInfo.FieldType.GetInterfaces().Any(x => x == typeof(IEnumerable)));
    IEnumerable<object>       enumerablefieldValues    = enumerablefields.Select(f => f.GetValue(objectToInterrogate));

    // merge the two lists together
    IEnumerable<object>       enumerableMembers        = enumerablePropertyValues.Union(enumerablefieldValues);
    return enumerableMembers.ToList();
}
```

One specific challenge I am investigating is how to serialize an enumerable (`Dictionary`, `List` or array `TValue[]`) where `TValue` is itself a complex type (e.g. a class that can be serialized).  This cannot be ascertained without knowing the type of `TValue`, but this cannot be retrieved from `IDictionary` or `IList` alone and these can only be enumerated with the type `object`.

This is the very specific point I am trying to investigate and potentially to control: how to determine `TValue` and then to work out if/how to serialize it in turn.  My idea is to cast to more-specified generics with known type parameters but I get a bit lost at this point.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Casting is inherently a compile-time operation.  Casting to a type only known at runtime makes no sense.  You can't call your method if its types are not known at compile-time.

Comment: The approach here seems wildly off-course.  Instead of asking for a specific solution, can you please describe the specific *concrete* problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: You can use Reflection or covariance, depending on your scenario.

Comment: @DavidL have updated the original question.  Please bear with my ignorance ... trying to learn a new area.

Comment: @SLaks - I do quite a lot of casting between types not known at compile-time.  e.g. List<IParent> members to their IChild interface.  e.g. List<IAnimal> can contain elemenst that have sub-interfaces ICat and IDog but these are only known at run-time.

Comment: This is a similar question but doesn't answer the problem.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363894/how-to-serialize-idictionary

Comment: And this looks interesting   http://matt.berther.io/2004/06/14/serializing-an-idictionary-object/

Comment: @BitRacketeer: But you can only cast _to_ a type specified at compile-time.

Comment: You need Reflection.  Lots of it.

Comment: You can definitely access the items in a dictionary via the non-generic `IDictionary` interface by using its [`Item[object]` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.idictionary.item(v=vs.110).aspx). What you're getting out is the same object, whether it comes from `IDictionary.Item[]` or `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>.Item[]`. The only difference is the _static type_ of the object, and you need to forget about static typing and casts since those are strictly compile-time concepts and do not apply to what you're doing at runtime.

Comment: I am investigating and will advise in due course.  I appreciate that people have been constructive here, while I continue to explore this field.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

@SLaks points out in the comments:

> Casting is inherently a compile-time operation. Casting to a type only known at runtime makes no sense. You can't call your method if its types are not known at compile-time.

That's absolutely right. You can, of course, still call the intended method at runtime, but you'll need to use (more) reflection to do it, since you have no way to get the compiler to generate a statically-typed call.

To do this, take the `Type` object you already constructed using `MakeGenericType()`, and call [`GetMethod()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getmethod(v=vs.110).aspx) on it to get the `Type.MethodInfo` object corresponding to the method to call. Then, call [`MethodInfo.Invoke()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
Type dictType = typeof(SerializableDictionary<,>).MakeGenericType(keyType, valueType);

MethodInfo method = dictType.GetMethod("MyMethod");
object returnValue = method.Invoke(dictionary, new object[] { /* arguments */ });
```

---

#### TMI...

When you write `dictionary.MyMethod()`, the C# compiler generates a [`Callvirt`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.callvirt(v=vs.110).aspx) IL (byte code) instruction. The object to call the method on (and the arguments to the method) are pushed onto the stack, and the argument to `Callvirt` is the metadata token corresponding to the type-qualified `ISerializableDictionary<TKey,TValue>.MyMethod` method. This is the normal calling mechanism in .NET. When you (and the compiler) don't know what `TKey` and `TValue` are at compile time, there's no way to get the right metadata token for the method, and no way to generate the `Callvirt`. That's why you have to use the reflection API.

You can, however, use something like [`DynamicMethod`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.dynamicmethod(v=vs.110).aspx) to *generate your own IL* and JIT it at runtime. Once JITted, the call is just as fast as one statically generated by the compiler. There is of course significant overhead to generating a dynamic method, but it's a one-time overhead.

Of course, @DavidL points out:

> The approach here seems wildly off-course. Instead of asking for a specific solution, can you please describe the specific concrete problem that you are trying to solve?

That, too, is absolutely right. So **don't do what I just suggested** unless you really, really know what you're doing and have a really, really good reason. (Hint: You don't.) But I thought this information might give you a better overall picture of why you can't do what you expected to do.